# What is the best way for combining data from multiple arrays enclosing semicolons?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Let me explain bellow practically what i have and have i need

I'll be using this data in PHP, MySQL and WordPress Project, Currently I have these data in JSON file.

array_texts:

```
Link Text 1; Link Text 2; Link Text 3
```

array_links

```
https://url1.com; https://url2.com; https://url3.com
```

this is not limited to 3 i have more & less.

I need the best solution to use huge data from JSON to PHP/Wordpress with MySQL (Which ever works faster)

**Expected result for each** [Link Text](https://url.com)

```
<a href="https://url.com">Link Text</a>
```

and the whole combination as array or something like:

[Link Text 1](https://url1.com); [Link Text 2](https://url2.com); [Link Text 3](https://url3.com)

```html
<a href="https://url1.com">Link Text 1</a>; <a href="https://url2.com">Link Text 2</a>; <a href="https://url3.com">Link Text 3</a>
```

Comment: It seems you'll need to read the data from the files and use it to generate HTML strings. Where are you in the process and how are you getting stuck? Will you then be storing the strings in a database?

Comment: what to you mean by 'huge data'? Give approximate values? e.g. millions of items? Megabytes of text?

Comment: ah! i have around 100K rows @RyanVincent

Comment: yes you are right @showdev but I asked for best ways i know some ways which takes long time for queries with php/mysql like array_map

Comment: " data in CSV/Excel/JSON files." well which one or all 3? each would require a different approach

Comment: JSON please @tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use `explode` and `implode` to break the string, combine them with `array_map` ([manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) - notice the use of `null` in the function) and `foreach` as:

```
$array_texts = explode("; ", "Link Text 1; Link Text 2; Link Text 3");
$array_links = explode("; ", "https://url1.com; https://url2.com; https://url3.com");

$arr = array_map(null, $array_texts, $array_links);
foreach($arr as $aa) {
    $az[] = '<a href="' . $aa[1] . '">' . $aa[0] . '</a>';
}
echo implode("; ", $az);
```

This will give you the desire output

Live example [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/FT1YX)