# How to convert strings to 2D array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, twig

I have 2 strings which returns me the url and status from a curl call. I want to combine these two strings and create an array so that I can convert back to json object to fetch it in the twig.

I have tried using the `explode()` and the `array()` function.

```
$url = 
"'http://www.testsite.com','http://www.google.org','http://www.fb.net'";
$status = 200,300,404;
var testArray = array($url,$status);
```

I want to make my array look like :

```
testArray[0][$url] = http://www.testsite.com and 
testArray[0][status] = 200
```

Comment: Don't you need quotes around the value of `$status`?

Comment: You need to remove the single quotes around the URLs after you explode it.

Comment: `var testArray` in PHP? `testArray[0]` should be `$testArray[0]`, right? `testArray[0][$url]` should be `$testArray[0]['url']`? Where are you using `explode()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way for combining data from multiple arrays enclosing semicolons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602078/what-is-the-best-way-for-combining-data-from-multiple-arrays-enclosing-semicolon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode both strings, then loop over them and push an associative array with the values onto the result array.

```
$testArray = [];
$url_array = explode(',', $url);
$status_array = explode(',', $status);
foreach ($url_array as $i => $u) {
    $u = trim($u, "'"); // remove surrounding quotes
    $s = $status[$i];
    $testArray[] = ['url' => $u, 'status' => $s];
}
```